# Where can I purchase a legal Xanathar's Guide to Everything PDF?

Tags: dnd-5e, books

Hardback books take up so much room I don't have.... is there a legal PDF somewhere I can purchase?

Comment: [Related] [Is there a legal way to get D&D 5e core rulebook PDFs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47655)