# Can the Polymorph Other spell restore to flesh a character turned to stone by a medusa?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, polymorph

I have a character turned to stone by a medusa. The mage in the party has a *polymorph other* spell in her repertoire. Can that be used to restore to flesh (in a different body, I suppose) a person turned to stone?

I guess one of the fundamental questions that needs to be answered is, is a person dead when turned into stone, or merely in some kind of stasis (paleogenics instead of cryogenics, I guess)?

In the real world I would say someone is dead when turned to stone, but what about in a magical world? If I recall correctly, *Monster Manual I* referred to medusa victims as "living stone"- whatever that is. Of course, I could be wrong about MMI - I can't find a copy. But even if I did find that phrase - would it matter? "Living stone" is not alive in the real world. I'm confused.

Comment: Are you actually playing *Dungeons & Dragons 3e*? (That's not, like, me being snide or anything! It's just that there's no *polymorph other* spell in *3.5*; instead, there's *baleful polymorph* and *polymorph*.)

Comment: @Rogem See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comments were removed. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the [removed discussion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) in comments, I’m concerned that this might actually be a 5th edition question. Could you clarify which D&D edition you’re playing?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am fully aware of that answers should be kept to answers. However, I also do not want to answer a 3.5e question, as I would be unable to reference rules. A better cause for removal would've been extended discussion :)

Comment: @Rogem Nah, there was definitely answering — what the answer might be was the subject of the discussion. We’re more lenient on discussion, since it can be productive. Answering is always damaging to site function though and we don’t extend any tolerance for it.

Comment: I guess I'm playing 5th edition, I just look up "SRD _____ " on the internet for the rules. Hey I'm 50 years old and coming back to play D & D after year and years away (Like, what, 15 -20 years? I don't know...). Last I played was 3.5e. But I like the SRD rules better. Perhaps one of you young trendy types can actually tell me what I am playing...

Comment: There are multiple games and editions that can come up when searching “SRD (thing to look up)”, so that’s not enough for us to tell you what you’re playing—it’s even possible you’re using a mix of partially-incompatible pieces from different games. We can probably more-or-less answer this (and unhold it) if you can track down the exact SRD source(s) you’re using for *polymorph other* and for the medusa stats you used in the encounter, and [edit] those links into the question.

Comment: I always look for information on dandwiki.com. I don't know where those rules come from. I just know that after solitaire test playing, I like their rules the best.

Comment: Actually, I think, what I want to do here is lookup SRD 5e _____. Those are the rules I want to follow. You can keep this on hold, or delete it, or whatever, because I don't know where I got my info, to be honest. I just looked up SRD wish and this wish spell would cost a magic-user (at least) 5,000 XP to cast. That's 3.5e. right?  I know it's not 5e, and 5e is what I want and like best.

Comment: dandwiki is notorious in the D&D community as an unreliable reference source. You might be interesting in the answers to [Is there a legal way to get D&D 5e core rulebook PDFs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47655/321)